# Can't get packages without wifi, but can't get wifi without package

Tags: networking, drivers, apt, package-management, lubuntu

I don't know what I'm doing and hope someone can help me. Wifi and Ethernet drivers both "DISABLED", don't have the packages to install or update almost anything, and it seems like everything I try to do needs installation.

I have no secondary computer to transfer packages on a flash drive, have no way to get them online without wifi, and no way to get wifi without wifi package.

All I want to do is get the wifi working and run Lubuntu GUI. THATS ALL.

I THINK IM GOING CRAZY

Wifi driver is Qualcomm atheros qca9565/ar9565

Comment: Where are you getting the information that wifi and ethernet is disabled? command? GUI? What version of Lubuntu?

Comment: From terminal when I input audio lshw -class network it gives me a list of info on both, each with the word DISABLED on top.  I would settle for any version of lubuntu at this point if i could get one but it seems like I can't do anything, everything needs a package

Comment: The driver for your wireless, *ath9k* is already installed in recent versions of Ubuntu. DISABLED usually means that the wireless switch or key combination is set to turn off the wireless radio. Check from the terminal: `rfkill list all`

Comment: Ok it says I need to install Riki's, so when I do: "reading ackage lists ... done" "building dependency tree" "Reading state information ... done" "E: Unable to locate package rfkill"

Comment: When you click the Network Manager icon, are Networking and Wireless enabled? https://www.eui.eu/Images-2011/ServicesAdmin/ComputingService/eduroam/eduroamUbuntu(1).png

Comment: I don't have any desktop, desperately want to download one, but to download I need the packages, to get packages I need wifi, to get wifi I need a package ..., only ttyl/command terminal

Comment: I will propose an answer! What version of Ubuntu? `lsb_release -d`

Comment: WIFI IS PREFERRED

Comment: One last detail: `cat /etc/netplan/*`

Comment: Ubuntu  16.04 the default version of it yesterday. Ok trying that

Comment: "No such file or directory" version is ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: Was I supposed to replace the asterisk * with wifi network or something?

Comment: Nope. If there were *any* file in there, it would have read out its contents. There isn't any such file, so we needn't modify it. It is sometimes helpful to know what isn't there.

Answer (score 3):

We will edit one configuration file and get the wireless connected. First, confirm that your wireless interface is wlp1s0:

```
ifconfig
```

Once confirmed, next do:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Amend the file to read:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlp1s0
iface wlp1s0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <your_router>
wpa-psk <your_wpa_key>
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor. Next, do:

```
sudo ifup -v wlp1s0
```

Did you connect? Test:

```
ping -c3 www.ubuntu.com
```

It may take a reboot.

**EDIT:** Your wireless is blocked by the airplane mode button. Please do:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist ideapad_laptop"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r ideapad_laptop
exit
```

Now the button will probably work. Next, try again:

```
sudo ifup wlp1s0
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74254/discussion-on-answer-by-chili555-cant-get-packages-without-wifi-but-cant-get).